# why is yii omitting values from query with double inner join?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

the following Yii model method should return 2 values, name and descrition, per record, instead it only returns the description. the same query works perfectly when executed directly in MySQL. is Yii preventing one of the joins to be executed?

```
public function reportEducation(){
  $criteria = array(
    'select' => "
                 concat(person.name_first," ",person.name_last),
                 group_concat(person_studylevel.description)",
    'join' => "
       inner join person on junior = person.id
       inner join person_studylevel on level = person_studylevel.id",
    'group by' => 'junior'
  );
  return PersonEducation::model()->findAll($criteria);
}
```

this is my query:

```
select 
   concat(person.name_first," ",person.name_last) as name,
   group_concat(person_studylevel.description separator ", ")
from person_junior_education
  left join person on junior = person.id
  left join person_studylevel on level = person_studylevel.id
group by junior
```

part of it seems to have something to do with the concat_group function, because if i remove it, it shows the description field correctly.

but the names field never shows up. maybe the problem is how yii handles the mysql functions?

Comment: please mention the query

Answer (score 1):

My Advice is, *do not use CActiveRecord for complex queries* it is just not made for that, it is not a replacement for SQL either. Its only there to take CRUD actions on rows easy.

What I would do, is create a [view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28database%29), and then create a Model for that view. so you can then simple do:

```
PersonEducationView::model()->findAll(); // easy
```

**But** if you must use active record, then may be create 2 attributes in your `PersonEducation` model, so that it has some place to store the results of the query, also update your query to use aliases, so that it knows where to store them:

```
   // protected/models/PersonEducation.php
   public $fullname;
   public $description;

   public function reportEducation(){
       $criteria = array(
       'select' => "
            concat(person.name_first," ",person.name_last) AS fullname,
            group_concat(person_studylevel.description) AS description",
        'join' => "
           inner join person on junior = person.id
           inner join person_studylevel on level = person_studylevel.id",
       'group by' => 'junior'
       );
       return PersonEducation::model()->findAll($criteria);
    }
```

*Disclaimer: totally untested*

Comment: i tried it with the additional attributes and aliases but that didnt help. i ended up using `Yii::app()->db->createCommand("")`. works like a charm :)

Comment: Ohh yeah, createCommand is to send SQL directly. you can also give it a try to the [query builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder#preparing-query-builder) it abstracts things a little more (I still preffer a view)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but this may be the case because you are not properly calling your column names as Yii is automatically aliasing the table of the model you are using with "t". So if you are refering to a column of your PersonEducation model you would need to prefix it with "t." to be sure your are calling the right one.
If you want to change the alias you can use CDbCriteria's "alias" property, setting it to something meaningful like "person_education" or something like that. Hope it helps

Comment: no, that doenst fix it. also, i havent had issues with scoping of the fields of the base table.

Comment: You should use the debug toolbar  http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-debug-toolbar/ which will show you all the queries that are sent to MySQL during a request (as long as they are not done during an AJAX request of course)

Comment: pretty! but it only shows queries SQL and profiling information, not the result sets or information about them

Comment: Yes but you can check wheter the queries are the same as the ones you used when querying MySQL directly. And by the way: Syntax error? "group.concat" vs. "group_concat" in the Yii version

Comment: Ah and you you did not define an alias in your selects. e.g.: The "as name" part is missing too

Comment: yea i misspelled group_concat.
and no matter how many attributes and aliases i added, that didnt solve it ;)